# Infinite loop appending Ajax data to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a `div` to make a notification box that can only be seen after a click on my main menu. I am fetching data from a table named `shop` from this `notifi.php` file:

```
$result = array();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM shop';
try { 
  $stmts = $db->prepare($query); 
  $results = $stmts->execute(); 
  if($results == true) {
    $done = true;
  }
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
  die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}

$row = $stmts ->fetchAll();
if($done) {
  foreach($row as $rows) {
    array_push($result, $rows); 
  }
  echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
}
```

This produces JSON:

```
{
  "result": [
    {"id":"1","fruitname":"apple","cost":"200"},
    {"id":"2","fruitname":"banana","cost":"100"}
  ]
}
```

I have three columns—`id`, `fruitname` and `cost`—so the PHP and JSON seem fine. Now with jQuery, I am adding that JSON encoded data to the notification `div`. This lets me update my `div` information whenever the database updates, without a page reload. Everything was fine, until I realized my jQuery code appears to loop over my data infinitely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(done,200);
});

function done() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    updates();
    done();
  }, 200);
}

function updates() {
  $.getJSON("notifi.php",function(data) {
    $.each(data.result,function() {
      $(".display_noti").append(
        "<span>From: "+this['fruitname']+"</span> <span>To: "+this['cost']+"<br><br></span>"
      );
    });
  });
}
```

`.dispaly_noti` is my `div` class, and inside it, as you can see, I am appending a `span` for each element of JSON data. Can you help me see what might be causing an infinite loop appending to my `div`?

Comment: That looks a good question now :D Thanks for edit @Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updates` function only ever `appends` to your div - nothing is ever removed - so every 200ms, you fetch your data again and add a new batch of `span`s to what's already there.

To fix it, simply use [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/), which clears out the children of an element, then add the new batch of data.

```
function updates() {
  $.getJSON("notifi.php", function(data) {
    $(".display_noti").empty(); // Clear out the div
    $.each(data.result, function() { // Add each new element
      $(".display_noti").append(
        "<span>From: "+this['fruitname']+"</span> <span>To: "+this['cost']+"<br><br></span>"
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Another thing that might make this look like a fast infinite loop is that since you're using Ajax, you might be calling `done` again before `updates` finishes. `getJSON` returns immediately, `updates` then returns, and you call `done` again, which will enqueue the next iteration in 200ms. If your server takes 300ms to respond, the timer has already fired and there already a second request in flight. That will only bog the server down more, which worsens the problem. To fix it, you can `setInterval` at the end of your work `updates` instead, so you're guaranteed to only be making one request at a time.

```
function done() {
  setTimeout(updates, 200); // Call updates in 200ms
}

function updates() {
  $.getJSON("notifi.php", function(data) {
    $(".display_noti").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function() {
      $(".display_noti").append(
        "<span>From: "+this['fruitname']+"</span> <span>To: "+this['cost']+"<br><br></span>"
      );
    });
    done(); // The request came back and we're finished. Set a new timer.
  });
}
```

There are a couple other things to also consider:

- 200ms is quite fast. You might want to slow down to 1000ms or more, unless your DB really is changing so quickly and your server can handle it.
- You're loading the entire DB content every time. If you keep track of the last time you fetched data and only fetch new items, you'll save a lot of load on the server and network. In that case, you don't need `empty`, you can just `append` as you are now.

Comment: Thank you so..much for your help bro.I will keep all those things in mind which you said :)